# NUnit TestFixtures do not work with RestSharp

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit, hook, restsharp

I'm trying to use `NUnit` `TestAttributes` to create and delete a `RestSharp` `RestClient`

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using RestSharp;

namespace Sanitized.Sanitized.Steps
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SetupAndTeardown
    {
        public RestClient restClient;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {

            restClient = new RestClient();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {

            restClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But, I get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when trying to use this in another class i.e. with my automated steps.

I don't understand this, as I thought code that's in the `[SetUp] [Teardown]` attributes are called at the beginning and end of the test respectively.

Comment: Ok, but where is the test? `> So long as the class contains at least one method marked with the Test, TestCase or TestCaseSource attribute, it will be treated as a test fixture.`

Comment: Should also take a look at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown-Changes

Comment: also are you by chance using async?

Comment: I'm not using `async`.  I am not sure where to put `[TestCase]`

Comment: Think I might have run into a problem.  `NUnit TestFixtures` rely on inheritance and my test methods (which are in another class)  are already inheriting another class. Since C# does not support multi-inheritance I don't think I will be able to use `TestFixtures` .  Am I right?

Comment: It looks like that's correct as per their [example](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown) with the base class.

Comment: Why are your test methods in another class? Tests should be completely separate from your implementation. Side note, try to use dependency injection instead of inheritance whenever possible. Inheritance is almost never the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You created a `TestFixture`, which is a class that contains tests. If the fixture had any tests, then NUnit would run them and would also run the setup before each test and the teardown after each test. Since you have no tests, that isn't happening. NUnit recognizes the fixture but finds nothing to run there.

You say that you have a problem when you "use" this fixture in another class. Test fixtures are not intended to be "used" by other code. Rather, they are run by NUnit.

For a better answer about how to do what you are trying to do, we first need to know what you are trying to do. When do you want the "setup" and "teardown" to run? How often should they run? Depending on those things, I can update this answer.

Replying further to your comment... If your tests are in another class, then that class is your test fixture. Is there a reason you don't want it to be the fixture?